# Ruby on Rails Submit button not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, controller

I the look and feel of my new form for a new Opportunity (put in some tables, css, etc...) and now my "submit" button won't work. It doesn't create a new record nor does it perform any of the validation callbacks... I was wondering if anyone could help me? Here is the output from the terminal:

```
Started GET
 "/opportunities/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=e31DA70sbl%2B3%2FJCeoTcxCTWncLcVs6R6FvR0ZU6vSmA%3D&opportunity%5Bdepartment%5D=DHS&opportunity%5Bagency%5D=asdf&opportunity%5Bprogram_name%5D=fdas&opportunity%5Bstage%5D=Assessment&opportunity%5Bcapture_manager%5D=Sherry+Hwang&opportunity%5Bprogram_description%5D=asdfadsf&opportunity%5Bnew_or_recompete%5D=Re-Compete&opportunity%5Bincumbent%5D=Adsf&opportunity%5Bcurent_contract_vehicle%5D=fdas&opportunity%5Bnew_contract_vehicle%5D=fdas&opportunity%5Bsb_set_aside%5D=Yes&opportunity%5Bprime_or_sub%5D=Prime&opportunity%5Bnaics%5D=234&opportunity%5Brfi_date%281i%29%5D=&opportunity%5Brfi_date%282i%29%5D=&opportunity%5Brfi_date%283i%29%5D=&opportunity%5Brfi_submitted%5D=&opportunity%5Best_rfp_date%281i%29%5D=&opportunity%5Best_rfp_date%282i%29%5D=&opportunity%5Best_rfp_date%283i%29%5D=&opportunity%5Best_full_value%5D=fdsa&opportunity%5Best_workshare%5D=asdf&opportunity%5Bp_win%5D=asdf&opportunity%5Bgovwin_id%5D=adsf&commit=Create+Opportunity"
 for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-02 10:10:16 -0400
     Processing by OpportunitiesController#new as HTML
       Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"e31DA70sbl+3/JCeoTcxCTWncLcVs6R6FvR0ZU6vSmA=",
 "opportunity"=>{"department"=>"DHS", "agency"=>"asdf",
 "program_name"=>"fdas", "stage"=>"Assessment",
 "capture_manager"=>"Sherry Hwang", "program_description"=>"asdfadsf",
 "new_or_recompete"=>"Re-Compete", "incumbent"=>"Adsf",
 "curent_contract_vehicle"=>"fdas", "new_contract_vehicle"=>"fdas",
 "sb_set_aside"=>"Yes", "prime_or_sub"=>"Prime", "naics"=>"234",
 "rfi_date(1i)"=>"", "rfi_date(2i)"=>"", "rfi_date(3i)"=>"",
 "rfi_submitted"=>"", "est_rfp_date(1i)"=>"", "est_rfp_date(2i)"=>"",
 "est_rfp_date(3i)"=>"", "est_full_value"=>"fdsa",
 "est_workshare"=>"asdf", "p_win"=>"asdf", "govwin_id"=>"adsf"},
 "commit"=>"Create Opportunity"}
      User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
       User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
       Rendered opportunities/_form.html.erb (7.4ms)
       Rendered opportunities/new.html.erb within layouts/application (8.1ms)
     Completed 200 OK in 53ms (Views: 49.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

And here is my Opportunity controller:

class OpportunitiesController < ApplicationController
        before_action :set_opportunity, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
        before_action :authenticate
        helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

```
      def index
        @opportunities = Opportunity.where.not(stage: 'Retired').order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.csv {send_data @opportunities.to_csv}
          #format.xls {send_data @opportunities.to_csv(col_sep: "\t")}
        end

      end


    def show
      @opportunity = Opportunity.find(params[:id])
      #render json: @opportunity

    end 

    def new
      @opportunity = Opportunity.new
    end


    def edit
    end

    def create
      @opportunity = Opportunity.new(opportunity_params)
      @opportunity.created_by = current_user.full_name

      respond_to do |format|
        if @opportunity.save
           @opportunity.created_by =  current_user.full_name
          format.html { redirect_to @opportunity, notice: 'Opportunity was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @opportunity }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @opportunity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        if @opportunity.update(opportunity_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @opportunity, notice: 'Opportunity was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @opportunity }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @opportunity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @opportunity.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to opportunities_url, notice: 'Opportunity was successfully destroyed.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end

    private
      def set_opportunity
        @opportunity = Opportunity.find(params[:id])
      end

      def opportunity_params
        params.require(:opportunity).permit(:department, :created_by, :capture_manager, :stage, :agency, :program_name, :program_description, :new_or_recompete, :incumbent, :curent_contract_vehicle, :new_contract_vehicle, :sb_set_aside, :prime_or_sub, :naics, :rfi_date, :rfi_submitted, :est_rfp_date, :est_full_value, :est_workshare, :p_win, :derated_sales, :govwin_id)
      end

      private

      def sort_column
        Opportunity.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "department"
      end

      def sort_direction
        %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction]: "asc"
      end
  end
```

My view:

```
 <%= form_for(@opportunity) do |f| %>
      <% if @opportunity.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@opportunity.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this opportunity from being saved:</h2>
          <ul>
          <% @opportunity.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>


      <table id="new_opp_form" style="width: 450px; background-color: white; border-style: none; border:1px orange;">

          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Agency</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :agency %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Program Name</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :program_name %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Stage</td>
            <td><%= f.select :stage, [[],['Assessment', 'Assessment'], ['Pre-Proposal', 'Pre-Proposal'], ['Proposal', 'Proposal'], ['Subitted', 'Submitted'],['Retired', 'Retired']] %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Capture Manager</td>
            <td><%= f.collection_select(:capture_manager, User.all, :full_name,:full_name,{:prompt => true}) %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Program Description</td>
            <td><%= f.text_area :program_description %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>New or Re-recompete</td>
            <td><%= f.select :new_or_recompete, [[],['New', 'New'], ['Re-Compete', 'Re-Compete']] %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Incumbent</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :incumbent %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Current Contract Vehicle</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :curent_contract_vehicle %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>New Contract Vehicle</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :new_contract_vehicle %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Small Business Set Aside?</td>
            <td><%= f.select :sb_set_aside, [[],['Yes', 'Yes'], ['No', 'No']] %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Prime or Sub</td>
            <td><%= f.select :prime_or_sub, [[],['Prime', 'Prime'], ['Sub', 'Sub']] %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>NAICS</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :naics %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>RFI Date</td>
            <td><%= f.date_select :rfi_date, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>RFI Submitted?</td>
            <td><%= f.select :rfi_submitted, [[],['Yes', 'Yes'], ['No', 'No']] %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Est. RFP Date</td>
            <td><%= f.date_select :est_rfp_date, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Est. Full Value</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :est_full_value%></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Est. Workshare (%)</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :est_workshare %></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

My routes file:

Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
  resources :test_users

  get 'profile/my_profile'

  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"

  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"

  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
  root :to => "sessions#new"

  get 'view_submitted/submitted'

  get 'view_action_list/seven'

  get 'show_number/thirty'

  get 'show_number/sixty'

  get 'show_number/year'

  get 'view_retired/retired'

  resources :users
  resource :sessions

  get 'report/report_page'

  resources :opportunities do
    resources :activities
    resources :updates
    resources :contacts
    resources :links

  end
```

Comment: Can you post the `new` method and `opportunity_params` method of your controller?

Comment: I added in all the code from my controller. not sure why it didn't show up the first time.. thx!

Comment: I see a `department`in the `params hash` and in `opportunity_params` but i can't see it in the `form code`.How the value is being passed for the `department`?

Comment: I didn't post my full form code in since some of it is sensitive information @Pavan. So there are some fields that are missing..

Answer (score 0):

First, your submit button is in your view, please post that. :)

Second, you're doing an `HTTP GET` with the parameters that would typically be in a `POST`.  Have you specified your `method: :get` in the form for some reason accidentally?

Comment: Hi - I added in my form... I'm not sure if I accidentally changed my method... if I did, how can I check and fix it? Thx for ur help!